# What is the difference between iptables and ip route table?

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, nat

Recently I am learning `iptables`, I know there are 5 independent tables, two of them are filter and nat tables. And I sometimes will look at `netatat -r` or `route` table, I know `ip` command can modify this routing table. I am a bit confused about these 2 kinds of tables:

1. routing table
2. nat and filter tables

They all can do something on packet traffic and looks they can do similar things, can someone tell me what are the differences?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `iptables` and `ip` have much the same relationship that `cat` and `catepillar` do - they start with the same first two letters. `iptables` is for managing the firewall. `ip` is for managing network interfaces, addresses, and routes

Comment: Consider also `nftables` as a replacement to `iptables`, `ip6tables`, `arptables`, etc.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/419659/iptables-vs-route

Comment: A routing table is *mandatory* for proper function of the IP network protocol; all the `iptables` functionality is *optional*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `iptables` is a tool, the `ip route table` is something used by the operating system to determine how to send network packets to its destination. With `iptables` on linux you can manage firewall rules e.g. redirect ports or block certain addresses. The `ip route table` (aka "routing table") is a kind of "maps" for your system to inform about paths to take to get somewhere. `nat` is something you can establish via the tool `iptables`, it can "translate" (the t in nat) network addresses into other addresses.

For example, if you have multiple systems in a network, you can use NAT to redirect all incoming traffic for the public port 80 (usually HTTP, or 4381 for HTTPS) to the system that should respond to your web requests. This could be any other port, and this redirection is done using **N**etwork **A**ddress **T**ranslation.